# dbt docs generate gives error : SSLError("bad handshake: SysCallError(-1, 'Unexpected EOF'

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

We are using dbt 1.5.3 along with Snowflake connector 1.5.2. and Python 3.11.4 I am facing an issue recently wherein I couldn't execute dbt docs generate. Everything else works fine without any issue. But when I use dbt docs generate, it takes around 25-40 minutes to finish the execution of command with error at the end

> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='xxxxxx.s3.us-xxxx-2.amazonaws.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /some_url (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: SysCallError(-1, 'Unexpected EOF')")))

Any help here would be highly appreciated!

I am using a Windows laptop. There are other team members in the team who has the same system configuration as mine, as well as same dbt/Snowflake configuration and they could execute everything along with dbt docs generate.

Tried debugging this with SnowCD and it passed all the checks. Everything at dbt end looks good too since everything else works fine. Not connected to any VPN either, system is updated with all the necessary Windows update.

Comment: is there a list of whitelisted IPs etc. in your org ? is it coming when you are connecting first time? something changed? Looks like dbt cant connect to SNF

Comment: The URL seems to be the one of the internal stage of the Snowflake account. Are you sure your SnowCD passed all tests for all the URLs from [SYSTEM$ALLOWLIST](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/system_allowlist)? Do you have any proxy set on your Windows machine?

Comment: @KoushikRoy We don't have any network policies so all the IPs are allowed. 
After digging in some more, I realized that it was the power/battery settings that was causing the problem. 
On Windows, my power setting was set to Best Battery Life instead of Best Performance, which was causing this. I believe dbt requires more cycles/memory/power to execute dbt docs generate and that settings was causing the issue.

Changing it back to Best Performance solved it. This is resolved now. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @Sergiu This is resolved.